# Install tensorflow-gpu in Anaconda with CUDA Compute Capability less than 3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have been trying to install tensorflow-gpu in Anaconda on Windows 10 with a graphics card that has Compute Compatibility 2.1. I keep getting the error below.
[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6goI.jpg)

`pip install tensorflow-gpu` works well but then I cannot import the library or create a tensorflow environment. Is there a workaround for this? Even if I get tensorflow-gpu installed, will I be able to run my model on the GPU without having Compute Compatibility 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to run any model on your GPU as Compute Compatility 3.0 is required (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)).

Your first attempt showed that you were missing some packages (numpy for instance). If you installed tensorflow-gpu with pip and you can't import the library that means that your python interpreter does not see the path where pip installs your packages.